# Rhodecode and GO continuous integration

Tags: mercurial, rhodecode, thoughtworks-go

I'm working with RhodeCode (someway similar to bitbucket) for some time now, and my team want to integrate a new CI tool named [GO](http://www.go.cd), this tool uses version control systems (mercurial, git, svn, etc), in our case mercurial on a RhodeCode repository.

The problem is that when I want to set the RhodeCode URL and credentials for this private repository, there is just a URL field, and not a 'user' and 'password' field.

I know mercurial repositories has the possibility to pass the user and password  through the URL (user:password@repo.com) and I tried it without success, it recognizes the user and password when I check the connection but when the pipeline is executed, an http authentication error jumps.

We can't use a local repository because we are a team working on this project.

I know there is a [text file with all these configurations](http://www.thoughtworks.com/products/docs/go/current/help/configuration_reference.html), but I couldn't find the way to put my credentials there to pull from our remote repository.

So, if some of you has had the same issue, I would be really grateful if you could answer this issue.

Greeting and many thanks!

Alejandro.

Comment: http://www.thoughtworks.com/products/docs/go/current/help/configuration_reference.html#hg

Comment: Hello Lazy Badger, as I wrote, I tried to put my credentials in the url without success.
Also, ssh is not an options for us in this project because customer's policies.

Answer (score 0):

To use your username and password in a Mercurial URL, you'll need to [URL-encode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) your username and password.

E.g: `user@example.com` with password `$ecre7` will use a URL like `https://user%40example.com%:%24ecre7%0A@example.com/myrepo`.